# moving angular modal controllers into separate files

Tags: angularjs, controller

I have a page controller on my site that includes several modals. Some of the modal controllers are getting robust, and I would like to move them into separate controllers without losing the scope of the outer page controller (the modal controller uses some of the page controllers functions and properties) - is this possible? So far I am getting errors to anything which references the outer controller. Here is a simple example of how I have it set up:

the page controller:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('outerCtrl', function(MetaService) {
    var thisCtrl = this;

    thisCtrl.someFunction = function() {
        //some cool functionality that will elvaluate something
    }

    function optionsModal() {
        var PageCtrl = thisCtrl;

        $uibModal.open({
            'controller': 'scripts/controllers/optionsModal.js',
            'controllerAs': 'ModalCtrl',
            'templateUrl': 'views/modals/optionsModal.html',
            'size': 'md'            
        });
    }   
});
```

the modal controller:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('optionsModalCtrl', function(MetaService) {
    var modalCtrl = this;

    function giveOptions() {
        if (PageCtrl.someFunction()) {
            //offer some option
        } else {
            //offer a different option
        }   
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [example](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) from official page:

```
 var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
      size: size,
      scope: $scope, // pass parent scope to modal instance
      resolve: {
        items: function () {
          return $scope.items;
        }
      }
    });
```

Comment: thank you, this makes sense, but does not seem to be working for me. i read the link and tried a couple different ways. Seems one would have to attach scope to everything they wanted the modal's controller to have access to - this is not something I want to do (I am discouraged from using $scope in my code), so i tried `$scope.pageCtrl = PageCtrl`  to pass the scope that way, which didn't work. Just for the sake of experimentation I did attach scope to a few things, passed scope in as a property of the modal, and still got the errors from the modal's controller :(